# Automatically version Asp.net Core Web App

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a web application in Asp.Net Core 2.0. In the `csproj` I have a version number with pattern `1.0.0.0`. I would like when I compile with VSTS that the pattern becomes `1.0.0.$Build.Id`, but I cannot find a way to do this.

I tried the [Update Assembly Info](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bool.update-assembly-info&targetId=8e218703-038c-4004-adf4-69ce4049005b&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList) VSTS extension this task but it does not work:

Comment: Have you looked at this extension? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=4tecture.BuildVersioning I haven't used it myself but I have heard positive things.

Comment: Do you get error while using update assembly info task? Provide the details of why it does not work.You can share the detail log on the OneDrive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many extensions in [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=assembly&target=VSTS&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) that can update assembly info, such as [Assembly Info](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bleddynrichards.Assembly-Info-Task).

You also can do it through PowerShell script with PowerShell task: [Auto assembly versioning in Visual Studio Team Services (or VSTS) build](https://mohitgoyal.co/2017/09/08/auto-assembly-versioning-in-visual-studio-team-services-or-vsts-build/).

```
Param
    (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$productVersion
    )

    $buildNumber = $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
    if ($buildNumber -eq $null)
    {
        $buildIncrementalNumber = 0
    }
    else
    {
        $splitted = $buildNumber.Split('.')
        $buildIncrementalNumber = $splitted[$splitted.Length - 1]
    }

    $SrcPath = $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY
    Write-Verbose "Executing Update-AssemblyInfoVersionFiles in path $SrcPath for product version Version $productVersion"  -Verbose

    $AllVersionFiles = Get-ChildItem $SrcPath AssemblyInfo.cs -recurse

    $versions = $productVersion.Split('.')
    $major = $versions[0]
    $minor = $versions[1]
    $patch = $versions[2]

    $assemblyVersion = $productVersion
    $assemblyFileVersion = "$major.$minor.$patch.$buildIncrementalNumber"
    $assemblyInformationalVersion = $productVersion

    Write-Verbose "Transformed Assembly Version is $assemblyVersion" -Verbose
    Write-Verbose "Transformed Assembly File Version is $assemblyFileVersion" -Verbose
    Write-Verbose "Transformed Assembly Informational Version is $assemblyInformationalVersion" -Verbose

    foreach ($file in $AllVersionFiles) 
    { 
        (Get-Content $file.FullName) |
        %{$_ -replace 'AssemblyVersion\("[0-9]+(\.([0-9]+|\*)){1,3}"\)', "AssemblyVersion(""$assemblyVersion"")" } |
        %{$_ -replace 'AssemblyFileVersion\("[0-9]+(\.([0-9]+|\*)){1,3}"\)', "AssemblyFileVersion(""$assemblyFileVersion"")" } |
    %{$_ -replace 'AssemblyInformationalVersion\("[0-9]+(\.([0-9]+|\*)){1,3}"\)', "AssemblyInformationalVersion(""$assemblyInformationalVersion"")" } | 
    Set-Content $file.FullName -Force
    }

    return $assemblyFileVersion
```